# How to get full GCP GCR image name using Golang to use in container-analysis for vulnerabilities

Tags: go, google-cloud-platform, gcloud, google-container-registry, google-artifact-registry

I would like to get a compiled list of image vulnerabilities from GCP similar to what shows in the console but in an automated report-type fashion. Using Golang, my thought process was to get the list of images and then get the vulnerabilities for each image.

I've got bits and pieces of this working but haven't been able to get the entire solution to work because one function only seems to work if I provide an image SHA value but I don't know how to acquire that programmatically.

I'm using this function to retrieve a list of images, which returns the image name as `projectid/reponame/image`:

```
func GetImageURLs() ([]string, error) {
    auth, err := google.NewGcloudAuthenticator()
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    fmt.Println(auth)
    registry, err := gcr.NewRegistry("gcr.io")
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    ctx := context.Background()
    repos, err := remote.Catalog(ctx, registry, remote.WithAuthFromKeychain(authn.DefaultKeychain))
    if err != nil {
        log.Fatal(err)
    }
    return repos, nil
}
```

My container-analysis function looks like:

```
func findVulnerabilityOccurrencesForImage(resourceURL, projectID string) ([]*grafeaspb.Occurrence, error) {
    // Use this style of URL when you use Google Container Registry.
    // resourceURL := "https://gcr.io/my-project/my-repo/my-image"
    // Use this style of URL when you use Google Artifact Registry.
    // resourceURL := "https://LOCATION-docker.pkg.dev/my-project/my-repo/my-image"
    ctx := context.Background()
    client, err := containeranalysis.NewClient(ctx)
    if err != nil {
        return nil, fmt.Errorf("NewClient: %v", err)
    }
    defer client.Close()

    req := &grafeaspb.ListOccurrencesRequest{
        Parent: fmt.Sprintf("projects/%s", projectID),
        Filter: fmt.Sprintf("resourceUrl = %q kind = %q", resourceURL, "VULNERABILITY"),
    }

    var occurrenceList []*grafeaspb.Occurrence
    it := client.GetGrafeasClient().ListOccurrences(ctx, req)
    for {
        occ, err := it.Next()
        if err == iterator.Done {
            break
        }
        if err != nil {
            return nil, fmt.Errorf("occurrence iteration error: %v", err)
        }
        occurrenceList = append(occurrenceList, occ)
    }
    return occurrenceList, nil
}
```

The problem is, if I use the image name as returned from `GetImageURLs` function, I get no response, but if I add the SHA value at the end of the image like this:
`https://gcr.io/project/repo/image@sha256:lotsofshastuffhere`
then I will get a response back like this:

```
name:"projects/projectID/occurrences/occurenceID" 
resource_uri:"https://gcr.io/project/repo/image@@sha256:lotsofshastuffhere" 
note_name:"projects/goog-vulnz/notes/CVE-2022-22822" 
kind:VULNERABILITY 
create_time:{seconds:1642427592 nanos:121248000} 
update_time:{seconds:1656480316 nanos:956141000} 
vulnerability:{severity:HIGH cvss_score:7.5 
cvssv3:{base_score:9.8 exploitability_score:3.9 impact_score:5.9 
attack_vector:ATTACK_VECTOR_NETWORK attack_complexity:ATTACK_COMPLEXITY_LOW 
privileges_required:PRIVILEGES_REQUIRED_NONE user_interaction:USER_INTERACTION_NONE 
scope:SCOPE_UNCHANGED confidentiality_impact:IMPACT_HIGH integrity_impact:IMPACT_HIGH 
availability_impact:IMPACT_HIGH} 
package_issue:{affected_cpe_uri:"cpe:/o:alpine:alpine_linux:3.12" affected_package:"expat" 
affected_version:{name:"2.2.9" revision:"r1" kind:NORMAL full_name:"2.2.9-r1"} 
fixed_cpe_uri:"cpe:/o:alpine:alpine_linux:3.12" fixed_package:"expat" 
fixed_version:{name:"2.2.10" revision:"r0" kind:NORMAL full_name:"2.2.10-r0"} 
fix_available:true package_type:"OS" effective_severity:HIGH} 
short_description:"CVE-2022-22822" 
long_description:"NIST vectors: AV:N/AC:L/Au:N/C:P/I:P/A:P" 
effective_severity:HIGH 
fix_available:true}
```

**How can I get the SHA value for an image so that I can use it to get a proper response for container-analysis?**

Go Play example: https://go.dev/play/p/Dv1ZJF9n1RX

Eventually I want to be able to do something like this:

```
    var vlist []vulnerabilities
    for i := range urls {
        v := findVulnerabilityOccurencesForImage(i)
        vlist = append(vlist, v)
    }
// do stuff like export to csv
```

resources:

- https://cloud.google.com/container-analysis/docs/automated-scanning-howto#viewing_vulnerability_occurrences
- https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/golang-samples/tree/793a4c2378ca1c56b1c066dd2077c100a3b1995f/container_registry/container_analysis

Comment: I am able to use the AR (Artifact Registry) api to get the images.  Are you able to transition from GCR to AR as outlined by [this guide](https://cloud.google.com/artifact-registry/docs/transition/transition-from-gcr)?  Note that GCR is being deprecated so new features will only be for AR

Comment: Not at this time but priorities may have shifted anyway.

Comment: Gotcha, if you have any questions feel free to comment; this space is evolving quickly and any feedback is appreciated